Issue with "." (dots) in URL while using spring boot application + Angular in production
I'm building a Spring boot + Angular application (using Jhipster, deployed in a docker container using JIB but that should not be important to this issue).
Everything works perfectly in development, but in production, URLs with a "." are not working when directly accessing them.
let's say we have this URL defined : /release/:product/:version
-> /release/superapp/1.1.0  is giving a 403 forbidden error if typed directly in the web browser url.
But if Im accessing this URL by using clicks and buttons, it works. So it seems that the router works fine, but spring boot is not redirecting url with dots to the index.html... and only in production.
I've seen a lot of similar error but with development webservers... and they should all be fixed now. So I don't really know if there's a configuration I can change to make it work...
Web :
"@angular/core": "17.3.6",
 ...

Backend :
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.5


Ok.. the issue was actually my first assumption : that it was not related to Jhipster (or docker).

Ok.. the issue was actually my first assumption : that it was not related to Jhipster (or docker).
The autogenerated application comes with default configuration. And one of them (the sdingle page application filter) prevents all path with a "." to redirect properly to index.html. I've commented the row below; and it works. For anyone using Jhpster with the same issue :
SpaWebFilter
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Request URI includes the contextPath if any, removed it.
    String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
    if (
        !path.startsWith("/api") &&
        !path.startsWith("/management") &&
        !path.startsWith("/v3/api-docs") &&
        !path.startsWith("/login") &&
        !path.startsWith("/oauth2") &&
        !path.startsWith("/websocket") &&
        // !path.contains(".") &&  <---- Comment this
        path.matches("/(.*)")
    ) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

